# Air Turbine in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

The turbine is supposed to draw air from the storage tank. When the air drawn, the pressure, temperature and mass of the air in the storage tank should be reduced. But that's not happening here but p,T,m are increasing. can anyone tell me why it is happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's very hard to say from two images. Please post your model code.

Comment: It is just above 30000 lines and this website is not allowing it

Comment: The modelica code shouldn't be that large, please check,